# Loose coupling in composition

Tags: c++, oop

I need help understanding loose coupling. How does one design a class that uses
composition to be loosely coupled, when a child object needs to communicate
with their parent object? Let me give an example:

We have this:

```
class A {
    private:
        B b;
    public:
        void foo();
};
```

How does the B object call the function foo() from its container class A? The obvious answer is "just pass a pointer from A to the b", but this is tight coupling, and an inflexible design.

Can you please give me a simple solution to this problem (in C++ or Java preferably)
or provide design techniques that deal with these kinds of problems?

My real life example comes from developing a game engine for a JRPG. I have this class:

```
class StateMachine
{
    private:
        std::map<std::string, State*> states;
        State* curState;
    public:
        StateMachine();
        ~StateMachine();
        void Update();
        void Render();
        void ChangeCurState(const std::string& stateName);
        void AddState(const std::string& stateName, State* state);
};
```

In every game loop `Update()` of `StateMachine` is called, which calls the `Update()` function of `curState`. I want to make `curState` is able to call `ChangeCurState` from
the `StateMachine` class, but with loose coupling.

Comment: They are coupled anyway since A contains B.

Comment: Make A an Observable. Make B an Observer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can decouple using interfaces.

Create an interface `F` that implements the `foo()` method and pass this into B. Let A implement `F`. Now b can call `foo()` on F without knowing or even caring it is implemented by A.

Answer (score 2):

One way to reduce the coupling in this situation is to define interfaces for the objects that will be used in composition. This ensures that any change to their implementations will not break anything provided they uphold the interface you've defined. If you depend on interfaces for composition, you'll find that you can always change your implementations without breaking your other classes.

Answer (score 1):

Given your update I'll give you a different answer.

I can think of four options

1. Pass an instance of `StateMachine` into each `State` and don't worry about it. This does couple them together but it could be argued they are tightly related anyway.
2. As has been mentioned create an interface which just contains the methods on `StateMachine` that you want to be visible to `State` and pass this into `State`. This is an improvement as you now limit what `State` can do to your `StateMachine` class.
3. Also mentioned is the use of Observer/Observable. Here your `State` would create events and fire them to all observers. In this case your `StateMachine` would have to observe all your `State`s and react accordingly. This is perfectly valid but probably a little overcomplicated, certainly to start with.
4. Another approach is to use something like an `EventBus`, created by the `StateMachine` and passed into each `State`. The `State` can fire events onto the event bus. The `StateMachine` can listen to events on the event bus and react accordingly. This is a simplification of the Observer pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If A uses B then it is ok to have it contained inside. The problem arises when B needs A to function properly, then both objects are coupled. Instead you should try passing only some values or references to B and not the whole object.

Refactor your code if you absolutely need the whole A object in B.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this (Java) :

```
public interface A {
    void foo();
}

public interface B {
    ...
}

public class BImpl implements B {
    public B(A a) { ... }
    ...
}

public class AImpl implements A {
    private B b = new BImpl(this);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about your design. How A and B are related i.e. if B is part of A then composition is fine. Basically, there are few ways you can access other class
1. By passing reference
2. Composition/Inheritance
3. Friend class